# Typeorm migration issue

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, express, typeorm

I have sandbox server and I have been working on it for long time. Now I want to make a staging server So I have copied sandbox database and up for staging. Then I installed the necessary modules and run `npm build`.

When I run `node dist` it tries to run database migrations even though the columns and tables are already exist. I am using typeorm framework of nodejs. And used typeorm migration feature. I did not expect the migrations to have run.

It gives me error like this:

```
{ error: column "is_service" of relation "departments" already exists}
```

Is there something I missed?

Comment: Could you check if your `migrations` table contains the migration names in your code?

Comment: Yes. i have given same name for migration table and code. In local i have again clone my code and works everything ok. Why only on staging server its not woking? It may have problem with NGINX?